# Delphi 2010 MySQL Update through ClientDataSet Failing

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress, tclientdataset

I am using Delphi 2010 and connecting to a MySQL database using dbexpress. The connection works 100% and I am retrieving my data. The problem comes when I am trying to update data through a dbGrid. I am running through all the entries in the table performing checks on them. When calling the ApplyUpdates method, I was getting "Record not found or changed by another user".

Changing the updateMode on the DataSetProvider to upWhereKeyOnly, I am now in the situation where I am receiving "Unable to find record, no key specified". I have tried adding

```
BasysClientDataSet.FieldByName('idPolicy').ProviderFlags := [pfInUpdate, pfInWhere, pfInKey];
```

this to the code, but I am getting the same error. I have tried adding the ProviderFlags to the SQLQuery but I am getting no such field "idPolicy"

Comment: The source code for dbExpress is included so you can debug to the location where the actual SQL UPDATE statement and its WHERE clause are created. It helped me to find the reason of a similar problem in a dbExpress app.

Comment: Hey Mjn, thanks for the reply, I am pretty sure I know why it is doing it, there is a despondency with some DateTimeStamps and floating point values when it transfers the data from MySQL to Delphi and back again, I have read up all over the Internet about it. Thats the reason I am looking to change the UpdateMode to upWhereKeyOnly and specify the primary key columns that it should use on the update. I have taken the query it is performing on the database and removed the columns causing the issue and run it manually on the database and it works correctly.

Comment: ok, so the main question (without using workarounds) is how to set the updatemode to upWhereKeyOnly without causing the "Unable to find record, no key specified" error message? Maybe if this is clearer somebody who knows it will answer. But on the other hand, upWhereKeyOnly is dangerous in multi-user environments because concurrent users can overwrite each others changes.

Comment: Yeah basically just need to tell it to use a specific key at runtime on the applyUpdates. |The program has been designed where users will only interact with 1 set of data at a time, therefore the upWhereKeyOnly will work perfectly for me, but I cannot seem to get the keys to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set provider flag pfInKey for all primary key columns just as you did but not in client dataset but source dataset. This used to help me even when I don't understand what the hell are fields doing in client dataset when db express ignores these settings? I would say its a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **ResolveToDataSet** property of the DataSetProvider component to **True**.

Comment: I have change the property to true and still getting the same error when trying to applyUpdates on the ClientDataSet, is there anything else I need to do to force the update to use a specific column as a key on the update?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

try creating this procedure and using it in the provider `BeforeUpdateRecord` event.

```pascal
procedure SetOriginFlags(Source, Dest: TCustomClientDataSet);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Source.FieldCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Dest.FindField(Source.Fields[i].FieldName) <> nil then
    begin
      Dest.FindField(Source.Fields[i].FieldName).ProviderFlags :=
        Source.Fields[i].ProviderFlags;
      if Dest.FindField(Source.Fields[i].FieldName).ProviderFlags <> [pfHidden] then
        Dest.FindField(Source.Fields[i].FieldName).Origin :=
          Source.Fields[i].FieldName;
    end;
  end;
end;
```